# How to layout pycharm like Spyder/Matlab?

Tags: pycharm, spyder

I am used to using spyder with the editor taking up half the screen on the left, a variable explorer top right and the python console bottom right. I want to make use of Pycharm's functionality so I want to switch however I would like to create a similar sort of screen lay out. How do I do this?